# Weird behavior with validation in Laravel, auto redirect on the same page

Tags: laravel, validation, redirect

I am having trouble with Laravel. I'm trying to validate a form. I do a dump to see my `$request` when I submit it. But it's automatically redirecting to another page. If I delete the validated part and keep the dump of `$request`, there is no redirection.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);

     $this->validate($request, [
        "model" => 'required|string|max:40',
        "brand"=> 'required|string|max:40',
        "engine"=> 'required|string|max:40',
        "fuels"=> 'required|string|max:40',
        "km"=> 'required|string|max:40',
        "price"=> 'required|string|max:40',
        "image"=> 'required|string|',
    ]);
 
}
```

**Request**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THLNL.png]

Comment: Failed validation redirects back with errors-its feature, not weird.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! 
Ok but i don't understand why ... I'm filling only with string shorter thant 40 chars, i'll try to investigate a little more.

Comment: dump($errors) on form and check whats wrong

Comment: I'm so silly ... Just because of an "s".
Thank's a lot for your help :p !!!!

Comment: could you add the result of this line `dd($request->all())`